# 2-sphere as a manifold example

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, spheres

Reading an introductive treatise on differential geometry, I come upon the usual concepts of manifolds, charts and atlases. As an example is showed the 2-sphere immersed in $\Bbb R^3$...but as (global) "chart" are used the spherical coordinates!
I thought that, for such manifold, we could use a 6 hemisphere charts set, or two stereographic projections...Where am I wrong?

Comment: The standard spherical coordinate system has singularities at the north and south poles. Thus as a chart it covers everything else, but not those two points, so you still need at least two charts to cover the sphere. That being said, there is no single solution to a problem that asks you to mention examples of something. Covering the sphere in six hemispheres or with two stereographical projections, or two different spherical coordinate systems are all valid examples of (non-maximal) atlases.

Comment: Thank you @Arthur. Indeed, even if the considered sphere is a surface, it is legit to use tridimensional coordinate sets - like spherical one - as charts?

Comment: It's spherical coordinates with a fixed $r$, so in practice it's two-dimensional, mapping a point in the sphere to its corresponding $(\theta,\phi)\in \Bbb R^2$.

Comment: And to be clear, no, a 2-dimensional manifold cannot admit any charts with three coordinates (homeomorphisms to $\mathbb{R}^3$.